# C# Windows Forms FormClosing event

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I am working with the `FormClosing` event

```
DialogResult dg = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

if (dg == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
}
else if (dg == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This code works perfectly, when I click on the X to close the Form:

1. CANCEL will return to the form without any changes made
2. NO will close the form instantly
3. YES will open the save dialog

Above is 100% correct, however, once the save dialog is presented, when I click on Cancel button inside the save dialog, it still closes the form - it should also return?

Comment: Don't call `saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);` directly. Write a method containing the logic, and call it from here and from the `saveToolStripMenuItem_Click()` handler. Then you can make the method return a bool to indicate whether the Save dialog was cancelled or not, and respond appropriately.

Comment: "when I click on Cancel button inside the save dialog, it still closes the form" are you sure you mean Cancel? Because when I try your code and click Cancel the Form does not close, but when I click **No** the Form closes, because there is no logic in your code to handle that case

Comment: Is above code in FormClosing event?

Comment: Hi  Mong Zhu, the cancel from the prompt Yes, No, Cancel works as it should. The cancel I'm referring to is the save dialog box's cancel

Comment: I don't see any code for a save dialog box. If you have problems with it, why don't you post the relevant code?

Comment: This code as it is in my closing event works as expected, No closes window, yes performs my fake save, cancel leaves the window alone

Comment: Please keep in mind - I'm referring to the cancel of the save as dialog box itself

Comment: Does the Cancel Button have its DialogResult set to Cancel?   If so that's setting the Forms DialogResult to Cancel when you click it, which will eventually close the dialog regardless of what you do on FormClosing (unless you manually change DialogResult to None in the FormClosing.)

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested by Matthew Watson you can create a helping method. Here is a short version of it:

```
private DialogResult SaveStuff() 
{
    return new SaveFileDialog().ShowDialog();
}
```

This can be used in the `saveToolStripMenuItem_Click` event like this:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = SaveStuff();

    if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But most importantly you can use it in the `FormClosing` event and check for the return value:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dg = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

    if (dg == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        if (SaveStuff() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
    else if (dg == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

This way the Form should remain unclosed when hitting the cancel button on the `SaveFileDialog`